# python how to split http request line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

here is my request line example:

```
GET https://example.com/hello?ageSelections=0&category=6000&productPeriodType=3&resourcePlace=resourcePlace AND 5089=5089-- PStU&twoCategory=6200 HTTP/1.1
```

I want to split this string and looking forward to result:

```
['GET', 'https://example.com/hello?ageSelections=0&category=6000&productPeriodType=3&resourcePlace=resourcePlace AND 5089=5089-- PStU&twoCategory=6200', 'HTTP/1.1']
```

thanks:-)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

Comment: Is that a valid request? What's with the spaces in the Request-URI? If you have a valid request, use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: @Galen it's my SQL injection payload, not a valid request :)

Comment: @caratpine Oh goodie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two step approach using `str.partition` and `str.rpartition` (could also be accomplished by a `str.split` and `str.rsplit` with a `maxsplit=1` parameter each time):

```
line = 'GET https://example.com/hello?ageSelections=0&category=6000&productPeriodType=3&resourcePlace=resourcePlace AND 5089=5089-- PStU&twoCategory=6200 HTTP/1.1'
method, _, rest = line.partition(' ')
url, _, protocol = rest.rpartition(' ')
parsed_line = [method, url, protocol]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a bit more precise with specifications like whether it's a string. But given that it is a string it should look like:

```
string = GET https://example.com/hello?ageSelections=0&category=6000&productPeriodType=3&resourcePlace=resourcePlace AND 5089=5089-- PStU&twoCategory=6200 HTTP/1.1

data = string.split();
```

Of course if it is not a string you can't do that.